# How to setup Eclipse CDT to use clang compiler?

Tags: c++, eclipse, compiler-construction, clang

I have compiled clang yesterday and now Im trying to use the compiler within Eclipse CDT.
How do I setup Eclipse CDT to build my C++ projects using clang?

Comment: this is not a duplicate, the llvm plugin does not work because the version is newer than 3.2

Comment: Can you explain in your question how the suggested duplicate does not apply?

Comment: My version is newer than the supported one in the thread link.

Comment: "Does not yet work with LLVM 3.2. Works with older versions. This is, because llvm-ld (linker) tool was removed from 3.2."